# Bundle created by PyInstaller fails to import module from external environment

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

My environment:

- python3.8
- Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- PyInstaller 5.4.1 (local package)
- requests  2.28.1

I want that bundle will not contain 'requests' inside but import 'requests' from host's environment.
When importing 'requests' in code it fails:

```
File "/myuser/m/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/compat.py", line 48, in <module>
    from http.cookies import Morsel
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.cookies'
```

My script imports 'requests'

```
import requests
```

In order to import 'requests' from host's environment:

1. Create bundle with **--exclude-module requests**
2. In script:

```
sys.path.append('/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
```

When executed as bundle it failed with:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.cookies'

Ok, that makes sense because PyInstaller did not know about http.cookies without scanning 'requests'. When I added in script

```
import http.cookies
```

it worked.

Without 'import http.cookies' in code, if I add to script the place where http.cookies lives

```
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3.8')
```

it doesn't work.

The problem is I can not predict dependencies for each 3rd party module. That's why I add to sys.path all folders of host.

The questions:

1. What's wrong with adding to bundled script's sys.path all folders of host?
2. Why is can find 'requests' from /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages but not 'http.cookies' from /usr/lib/python3.8
3. In general, how it's possible to debug bundle as a python?

Comment: why would you want to require the end user to have to already have a package installed in their own python enviornment instead of bundling it with the executable... This sounds like a terrible idea since you can never guarantee the version of the package, or that they even have it installed at all.

Comment: @Alexander I deliver docker image to aws